# Silverlight 3 & Deeplinking

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, deep-linking

I have a requirement to implement some deep linking into a Silverlight application and thought the new navigation framework in Silverlight 3 would be ideal.  However after doing some digging about it uses Uri's to 'swap' one piece of xaml for another using the Frame control.

What I'd like to do, is use the deep link to select it's relating item in an items control. Are there any lower level objects i can tap into to interact with the browser history directly (Obviously i could write my own implementation but i'd prefer ti if i could tap into the built in framework)?

Bit of a long shot.

J

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember much about Silverlight 3 navigation but you can do this by combining Silverlight 4 navigation and Prism 4.

See this blog post for the a full implementation.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kashiffl/archive/2010/10/05/integrating-prism-v4-region-navigation-with-silverlight-frame-navigation.aspx

Essentially the frame will handle part of the navigation and load the appropriate Prism module (unless it's already loaded) and then a view model handles an OnNavigated event to do the final selection of the item in your items control.